# connect20.magentocommerce.com closed?

Tags: magento-1.9

I know no one should use magento 1 anymore, but I've got a client who didn't migrate and now his backoffice is not working anymore.

The problem is identified (and can be resolved) : in a third party module (French Chronopost), there is a call made to check the last release (and it's done on EVERY admin page !) on

`http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Chronopost/releases.xml`

And since last friday at 14h30 UTC+2 time it gives a 404.

The following of the module is garbage as it assume that there will be something in the `simplexml_load_file` without testing and so throw an erro when trying to use the `$xml` it was suppose to return (and now returning false...)

I can't find any official announcement of the plug being pulled of for the site. Anyone know if there is one ?

Not announcement stating that Magento 1 won't be support anymore after june (we've repeated it several time to the customers), but one specific to the end of the connect20 site.

Thanks if you have more information !

Jean-Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly check this links, where then mention all the things.

1. https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/supporting-magento-1-through-june-2020
2. https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/support-magento-1-software-ends-june-30-2020

Comment: Yes, thanks, I just found https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/How-Extension-Developers-Can-Prepare-for-M1-End-of-Life/ba-p/446216 too, also stating "Removal of M1 extensions from repo.magento.com". It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it will do the trick for the client to admit they should have paid more attention when I started making them quotes 3 years ago !